# Ocaml - tree preorder/postorder/inorder

Tags: tree, ocaml, preorder

I have that definition of trees given in OCaml

```
type 'a tree = Node of 'a * 'a tree list;;

let rec fold_tree f (Node (x,l)) =
f x (map (fold_tree f) l);;
```

Can somebody help me how can I write for example preorder in use of fold_tree (without additional recursion). I know how I can do this without fold_tree but this makes me problem

So far I have got this:

```
let preorder t =
  fold_tree (fun x l -> 
    (fold_left(fun acc h -> h@acc) x l ) ) t;;
```

but ocaml consider t as tree list...

Comment: What have you written so far, and why does it not seem to be working?

Comment: @JeffreyScofield yes, you have right, I mentioned problem but I did not say anything about my trying. I edited a post.

Comment: Did you not take anything from [the answer to your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53263732/7943564)? If you follow those advices, what happens then?

Comment: ignoring open and hd does not matter there. But if it comes to another advices, or I didnt  understand them or there does not matter too in that situation

Comment: You don't think type annotations matter for understanding the cause of a type error?

Comment: what do you mean via type annotations there?

Comment: I mean you should specify the type of the functions, which is easier if you name them and probably why that advice was given. If you name them, you'd specify the entire function type: `let f: int -> int -> bool = fun a b -> a = b in ...`. Alternatively you can specify the types for each argument and the return type individually in-line, which the previous answer gives an example of.

Answer (score 0):

```
    OCaml version 4.02.3

# type 'a tree = Node of 'a * 'a tree list;;
type 'a tree = Node of 'a * 'a tree list
# let rec fold_tree f (Node (x,l)) =
  f x (List.map (fold_tree f) l);;
val fold_tree : ('a -> 'b list -> 'b) -> 'a tree -> 'b = <fun>
# let preorder t =
  fold_tree (fun x l -> 
    (List.fold_left(fun acc h -> h@acc) x l ) ) t;;
val preorder : 'a list tree -> 'a list = <fun>
```

You are using `x` as start value for the List.fold_left and append values to it. That makes x a `'a list` and therefore t must be `'a list tree`. Change `x` to `[x]` and you get:

```
# let preorder t =
  fold_tree (fun x l -> 
    (List.fold_left(fun acc h -> h@acc) [x] l ) ) t;;
val preorder : 'a tree -> 'a list = <fun>
```